# How to run firejail as root?

Tags: security, root, chroot, jails, firejail

How can I run firejail as a root user?

```
# firejail --seccomp firefox
Reading profile /etc/firejail/firefox.profile
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-common.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-programs.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-devel.inc
Error: --noroot option cannot be used when starting the sandbox as root.
```

Comment: Pray tell why do you want to run Firefox as root?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `/etc/firejail/firefox.profile` and comment or delete the `noroot` line